# Docker ApacheMQ connection from outside a container

Tags: docker, activemq-classic

I have created a Spring Boot consumer using ActiveMQ and loaded into into a Docker container. One way to connect the container to ActiveMQ  is to create a network on Docker and then load an ActiveMQ container/image onto that locker as part of the network:

```
docker run -d --name activemqcontainer -p 8161:8161 --network=network rmohr/activemq
```

This runs ActiveMQ from the container. To connect to it from the consumer I have in my `application.properties`:

```
activemq.broker.url=tcp://activemqcontainer:61616
```

This means that my consumer inside my container can connect to ActiveMQ running in another container.

Can I take the ActiveMQ out of the container and still connect to it?

So I could have the following Tomcat/Producer -> ActiveMQ -> Docker/container/producer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Containers usually inherit the networking from the host, so if you can access the ActiveMQ broker from the host, the containers should as well.